# When I try to access a SMB mounted folder from inside a Vagrant CentOS Virtual box on a Windows 8.1 system, my shell locks up

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, centos, smb, vagrant

I'm running Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.10 on Windows 8.1 and inside I'm running CentOS 6.5. I have a /windows mounted on my Windows machine through SMB. Normally I use the /vagrant vboxfs file system, but when I try to view the /windows directory, it locks up my shell. I can't use ^C, ^Z, nor can I send SIGKILL or any other signal from Putty.

```
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ mount
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
//10.0.2.2/aidc on /windows type cifs (rw)
/vagrant on /vagrant type vboxsf (uid=500,gid=500,rw)
```

Here is an strace of ls.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ strace ls /windows
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/windows"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x857000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd79000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39412, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 39412, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f63abd6f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PX\200\270>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=124624, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3eb8800000, 2221912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3eb8800000
mprotect(0x3eb881d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3eb8a1c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x3eb8a1c000
mmap(0x3eb8a1e000, 1880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3eb8a1e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@!\0\270>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47064, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3eb8000000, 2128816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3eb8000000
mprotect(0x3eb8007000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3eb8206000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x3eb8206000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\23@\275>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19016, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd6e000
mmap(0x3ebd400000, 2111776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3ebd400000
mprotect(0x3ebd404000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3ebd603000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3ebd603000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\36\300\273>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=33816, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3ebbc00000, 2126416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3ebbc00000
mprotect(0x3ebbc07000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3ebbe06000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x3ebbe06000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356A\267>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926800, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3eb7400000, 3750152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3eb7400000
mprotect(0x3eb758b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3eb778a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x3eb778a000
mmap(0x3eb778f000, 18696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3eb778f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\300\267>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22536, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd6d000
mmap(0x3eb7c00000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3eb7c00000
mprotect(0x3eb7c02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3eb7e02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3eb7e02000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340]\200\267>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=145896, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3eb7800000, 2212848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3eb7800000
mprotect(0x3eb7817000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3eb7a17000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x3eb7a17000
mmap(0x3eb7a19000, 13296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3eb7a19000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\23\200\273>\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=21152, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3ebb800000, 2113888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3ebb800000
mprotect(0x3ebb804000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3ebba03000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3ebba03000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd6c000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd6a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f63abd6a7a0) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb8a1c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb8206000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3ebbe06000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb778a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb7e02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb6e1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3eb7a17000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3ebba03000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f63abd6f000, 39412)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f63abd6aa70)         = 20555
set_robust_list(0x7f63abd6aa80, 0x18)   = 0
futex(0x7fff8e671fec, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fff8e671fec, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f63abd6a7a0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x3eb7805c60, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3eb780f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x3eb7805cf0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3eb780f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=2242612, f_bfree=557842, f_bavail=443922, f_files=570080, f_ffree=265231, f_fsid={1226513072, 1470288141}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x857000
brk(0x878000)                           = 0x878000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f63abd78000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 328
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f63abd78000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99158576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99158576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f63a5ed9000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=46, ws_col=142, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("/windows",
```

This is where it locks up. Here is the full version.

```
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I was able to partially work around this by going to the /windows SMB mount after Vagrant starts up and staying there with a program running (I assume keep a file open?). Otherwise it seems if no file handles were used after several hours, it would lock up when trying to access it again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 7. Windows cuts off connections that are deemed inactive, such as connections with no open file handles.

The Linux VM locks up because the CIFS driver doesn't like being disconnected and can't recover.

It affects processes because they are in an interrupted state waiting for the CIFS filesystem driver to come back, which never does. You can't kill them as to kill them requires sending an interrupt signal, but they're already in an interrupted state whilst waiting for the driver. [More details available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085868/attempt-to-access-remote-folder-mounted-with-cifs-hangs-when-disconnected).

You can prevent the problem by turning off the autodisconnect feature in Windows which worked for me. Just run in a command prompt:

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```